# Error due to issue of object declaration. (inconsistent datatypes)

Tags: sql, oracle, object, plsql

I'm using a function which returns a table  in the procedure. I want the procedure to display the contents of the table.

The code of the function is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE employee_attr AS OBJECT (
      employee_id                        NUMBER(6,0),    
      first_name                         VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) ,
      last_name                          VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) ,
      email                              VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) ,
      phone_number                       VARCHAR(20 BYTE) ,
      hire_date                          DATE ,
      job_id                             VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) ,
      department_id                      NUMBER(4,0) ,
      salary                             NUMBER(8,2) ,
      manager_id                         NUMBER(6,0) ,
      commission_pct                     NUMBER );

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE employee_table AS TABLE OF employee_attr;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_employee_data (
      col_name_in                       VARCHAR2,
      col_val_in                        NUMBER)


FROM 
    (SELECT employee_id, first_name,
            last_name, email,
            phone_number, hire_date,
            job_id, department_id,
            salary, manager_id,
            commission_pct FROM EMPLOYEES2 WHERE '|| col_name_in || '  = ' || col_val_in || ' ) e ';
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_query);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_query BULK COLLECT INTO required_employees;
RETURN required_employees;     
END;/
```

I want the following procedure to display the contents of the function.

```
PROCEDURE display_employee_data(
    col_name_in         IN  VARCHAR2,
    col_val_in          IN  NUMBER)

AS
    lv_query            VARCHAR2(1000);

    emp_data            employee_attr;

    TYPE employee_data_cur_tp IS REF CURSOR ;

    employee_data_cur   employee_data_cur_tp;


BEGIN

lv_query := 'SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, email,
                    phone_number, hire_date, job_id, department_id,
                    salary, manager_id, commission_pct 
             FROM TABLE(get_employee_data(' ||''''|| col_name_in || ''''||
            ' , ' || col_val_in ||' ))';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_query);

OPEN employee_data_cur FOR lv_query;

LOOP
  FETCH employee_data_cur INTO emp_data;
  EXIT WHEN employee_data_cur%NOTFOUND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_data.employee_id || '   ' || emp_data.first_name);

END LOOP;

CLOSE employee_data_cur;


END display_employee_data;
```

When I run the procedure, as follows

```
BEGIN
employee.display_employee_data('EMPLOYEE_ID', 30);
END;
```

It raises the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
ORA-06512: at "CHAITU.EMPLOYEE", line 394
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

> The line 394 is where the loop starts, before the fetch statement.

Please help me out to find the right way of object declaration, so that the error is resolved. Thank You

Comment: Is you `employee_table%ROWTYPE` not basically an element of `employee_attr`?

Comment: In the code you've posted EMPLOYEE_TABLE is an object collection, not a relational table, and thus it cannot be used with %ROWTYPE. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov when I specify the return type as `employee_attr`, it raises an error message that the return type should be a record or cursor variable. So, I've not specified the return type in the code that I posted in the question.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Thank you, for ur valuable inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object has to be initialized. The modified procedure is as follows:

```
PROCEDURE display_employee_data(
    col_name_in         IN  VARCHAR2,
    col_val_in          IN  NUMBER)

IS      
    emp_data           employee_attr  DEFAULT employee_attr(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                                        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                                        NULL, NULL, NULL);

    lv_query            VARCHAR2(1000);


    TYPE employee_data_cur_tp IS 
                              REF CURSOR ;

    employee_data_cur   employee_data_cur_tp;


BEGIN

lv_query := 'SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, email,
                    phone_number, hire_date, job_id, department_id,
                    salary, manager_id, commission_pct 
             FROM TABLE(get_employee_data(' ||''''|| col_name_in || ''''||
            ' , ' || col_val_in ||' ))';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_query);

OPEN employee_data_cur FOR lv_query;

LOOP
  FETCH employee_data_cur INTO emp_data.employee_id, emp_data.first_name, emp_data.last_name,
                               emp_data.email, emp_data.phone_number, emp_data.hire_date, 
                               emp_data.job_id, emp_data.department_id, emp_data.salary,
                               emp_data.manager_id, emp_data.commission_pct;
  EXIT WHEN employee_data_cur%NOTFOUND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_data.employee_id || '   ' || emp_data.first_name);

END LOOP;

CLOSE employee_data_cur;


END display_employee_data;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to omit %rowtype otherwise the code looks good. Thanks    

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE display_employee_data(
        col_name_in         IN  VARCHAR2,
        col_val_in          IN  NUMBER) 

    AS 

        lv_query            VARCHAR2(1000);

        emp_data            employee_table;

        TYPE employee_data_cur_tp IS REF CURSOR;

        employee_data_cur   employee_data_cur_tp;


    BEGIN

    lv_query := 'SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_employee_data(' ||''''|| col_name_in || ''''||
                ' , ' || col_val_in ||' ))';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_query);

    OPEN employee_data_cur FOR lv_query;

    LOOP
      FETCH employee_data_cur INTO emp_data;
      EXIT WHEN employee_data_cur%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_data.employee_id || '   ' || emp_data.first_name);

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE employee_data_cur;


    END display_employee_data;
```

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov     In the code, I was using a ref cursor. so, why am I getting the type mismatch. Can you suggest where I've to make the change.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I followed ur suggestions, still I'm getting the mismatch error.
When I'm using a ref cursor, I'm getting the following error.
`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -`
nd when I define the cursor to match the datatype, it is throwing the following error
`PL/SQL: Statement ignored
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PLS-00386: type mismatch found at 'EMP_DATA' between FETCH cursor
and INTO variables`
can you please sort the error out. thank you